# How to retain caption without the "Figure" being mentioned?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I'm writing a document and I want to keep it simple. Probably there won't be any ToC or any List of figures so below each figure I just want the name of the figure to be mentioned and nothing else. Like:  Figure 1.1: bla bla bla  without the "Figure 1.1"

Is that possible?

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example people can compile. That will help people to help you (and make it more likely they will!).

Comment: Even without any ToC or so, it is much better to say e.g. "Figure 1 shows ..." than to be talking about "The next-to-last figure illustrates ..."

Comment: I assume you were talking to me right?  :-)

Comment: You never accepted my answer. Have you considered doing that?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just did  ^_^   I was new to stackexchange back then that was the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package with the option `labelformat = empty` (see [page 6 of the manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf#page=6)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelformat = empty]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\caption{Something.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You can also use the starred version of `\caption`, i.e. `\caption*`, and then you don't need to parse the option to the package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\caption*{Something.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah... sorry..!!!  That was fast enough!  Yeah this one works perfectly!  Thanks a lot!  :D

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the updated respond fast enough and added one more comment  :D :D