# Capturing final figure caption using knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm writing a paper for the journal PLOSone.  They require that figure captions be placed in the article but not the figure itself (it's submitted separately).  So I'm wondering how to get `knitr` to spit out the figure caption w/o the figure.  Of course, this is not quite possible, since the figure number and hence caption isn't finalized until `LaTeX` has been run.  So this question may need to be migrated eventually, but maybe someone has an idea about the necessary steps.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}
% Bold the 'Figure #' in the caption and separate it from the title/caption with a period
% Captions will be left justified
\usepackage[aboveskip = 1pt, labelfont = bf, labelsep = period, justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = off]{caption}

\begin{document}

This is my document.  Here is a cool plot: Fig.~\ref{LabelA}.
<<  ChunkA, fig.cap = "\\label{LabelA}\\bf{A Figure.}" , echo = FALSE >>=
plot(1:10, 1:10)
currCap <- knitr::opts_current$get("fig.cap")
@

<<  ChunkB, results = "asis" , echo = FALSE >>=
cat("\n")
cat(currCap)
@

\end{document}
```

This isn't quite the right approach, for two reasons.  First, `LaTeX` can process this, but the output from `cat(currCap)` creates a duplicate label which confuses it.  Second, the line of text that I want in the final pdf is:

**Figure 1.  A Figure.**

but the information that this is Figure 1 and not some other figure is not known prior to compiling in `LaTeX`.  Here is a little piece of the tex file which shows the output from the above code where you can see how the duplicate label arises.

```
This is my document.  Here is a cool plot: Fig.~\ref{LabelA}.
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/ChunkA-1} \caption{\label{LabelA}\bf{A Figure.}}\label{fig:ChunkA}
\end{figure}
\end{knitrout}
\label{LabelA}\bf{A Figure.}
```

Anyone know a way to make this work?

Comment: Though I haven't tested it, can you post-process the generated LaTeX file (e.g., `sed`) to replace all `\includegraphics` with a 1-pixel graphic or even remove the graphic altogether and keep the `\caption`? [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204016/caption-without-figure-envirorment) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159410/how-to-retain-caption-without-the-figure-being-mentioned) are alternatives.

Comment: @r2evans Ah, good idea.  As it turned out, I solved the problem in the particular context I had as described in my answer below.  It's a challenge sometimes to integrate all the nice tools that are out there now, at least until a more seamless approach comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here is a solution to my own question in case anyone else wants/needs to do this.

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[nomarkers, nolists]{endfloat}
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\begin{document}

<< setUp, echo = FALSE >>=
# Function to report figure captions independent of figures, as required by PLOSone.
# Original idea from Yihui Xie but modified considerably.
# https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/070-caption-num.Rmd
# Function captures figure caption
x <- NULL
ii <- 0 # Current figure number
fn <- function(x) {
    ii <<- ii + 1 # save updated figure counter into global environment
    figString <<- paste('\\textbf{Figure ', ii, '.} ', x, sep = '') # Current caption saved in global environment
    return(x) # Return original fig.cap so it can be processed normally in the LaTeX figure environment
  }
@

This is my document.  Here is a cool plot: Fig.~\ref{LabelA}.
<<  ChunkA, fig.cap =  fn("\\label{LabelA}\\textbf{A Figure.}"), echo = FALSE >>=
plot(1:10, 1:10)
@

<< figStringA, echo = FALSE , results = "asis" >>=
cat(figString)
@

<<  ChunkB, fig.cap = fn("\\label{LabelB}\\textbf{Another Figure.} Some details about the figure.") , echo = FALSE >>=
plot(1:10, 1:10)
@

<< figStringB, echo = FALSE , results = "asis" >>=
cat(figString)
@

The second figure is Fig.~\ref{LabelB}.  That's all folks!
\end{document}
```

If you have `includegraphics` environments you will have to include a little code to write out the figure caption and increment `ii` so that the figure numbering remains correct.